# Saving SSH key in home instead of root

Tags: ssh, user-accounts, root, editing

When I try to create an SSH key using `sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa` I get the request:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

However, I would like the file to be saved in `/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa`. When I enter that directory I get this error:

`Saving key "/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory`

Any attempt to enter a different directory returns an error.

How can I generate the key in `/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa`?

EDIT: when I remove `sudo` I get this problem:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Saving key "/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: Not a directory
```

But shouldn't SSH create the directory?

Comment: Does the directory `/home/user2/.ssh/` exist?

Comment: Why do you call it with `sudo` in the first place?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I thought that .ssh would get created automatically?

Comment: @gronostaj I'm not sure, i got it from a guide,  I'll edit my question to give the output whenever I don't use `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to create an SSH key using `sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa` I get the request:
>
> ```
> Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
> ```

**By using `sudo` you ask to run the program under another account**, specifically root. So the keygen will run as root, create a key belonging to root, and of course it will use root's home directory to store that key.

To create files belonging to yourself (and to use your own paths, etc.) just don't use `sudo`.

And if not using `sudo` leads to weird permission errors, better investigate and fix those – they won't quietly fix themselves if you just `sudo` the whole thing; often that'll just make it worse.

> when I remove sudo I get this problem:
>
> ```
> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
> Enter file in which to save the key (/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa): 
> Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
> Enter same passphrase again: 
> Saving key "/home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: Not a directory
> ```
>
> But shouldn't SSH create the directory?

It should. But what the error message really means is that `/home/hduser/.ssh` **already exists – it's just something else than a directory.** It might be a file, a broken symlink, a symlink to a file, etc.

Again: investigate the situation. To see what `.ssh` actually is, run `ls -ld` on it. If necessary, rename the file/link/item or completely delete it.

Comment: Thanks! It worked when I removed the file. btw how does `ls -ld` tell me what the file  actually is. doesn't the `.` in front of the filename tell me that its a hidden directory?

Comment: No. The `.` in front of the filename only tells you that it's a hidden _something_, but does not in any way imply it's a directory. The actual item type is the 1st character of ls -l output (before permission indicators).

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason for this was an existing key in the same location in which the keygen tries to create the key.
Deleting the key via

```
 sudo rm -rf /home/ec2-user/.ssh
```

and re-running the same command did the trick.

P.S. I am working on a aws host. you can try doing

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.ssh
```

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. Firstly: a user owns every single file and directory under `/home/user`. There's no need to `sudo` to remove files / folders. Secondly: this will remove user's entire `.ssh`-directory, not recommended and unnecessary to resolve the issue. Thirdly: the accepted answer is correct. As one is creating ssh keys for themselves, it can be done with user's own privileges. `sudo`ing will cause the keys to be written in root's home folder where the user has no access to them anyway. I'd suggest either deleting this or explaining why such a drastic measure would be necessary.

Comment: Oh, so does deleting an existing id_rsa file under this directory work?

Comment: The specific problem in OP:s question was simply `sudo`. Creating a personal key pair, you simply give the command without it. There's not necessarily a need to delete anything, as`ssh-keygen` will in the beginning ask for the filename, which by default is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. If the user doesn't give a new filename, the existing one's simply overwritten. As key pairs are personal, they should be created by the user. For user1 to create a key pair for user 2, they can `su user2`, and the key will be saved as `/home/user2/.ssh/id_rsa` and user2 can use it. The given answer is correct and complete.